# How to query multiple relationships in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm kinda stuck here while querying multiple relationships in laravel eloquent I had the raw query like

```
SELECT * FROM tblSchedules,tblUserHomeCourts,tblHomeCourts
 where tblHomeCourts.userId=6 
 and tblHomeCourts.homeCourtId=5
   and (tblSchedules.timeFrom <= 1495617580
    and tblSchedules.timeTo >= 1495617580) 
    and tblUserHomeCourts.userHomeCourtStatus=1
     and tblSchedules.scheduleStatus=0
```

now I need to query this raw query into laravel eloquent. I've tried to to do so like this

```
$getSchedule= Schedule::with(['userSchedule' => function($query) use ($userId,$homeCourtId,$timeFrom, $timeTo) {
        $query->where(['userId'=> $userId,'homeCourtId'=>$homeCourtId,'userHomeCourtStatus' => Constant::STATUS_1]);
    }]) ->where('timeFrom','<=',$timeFrom)
        ->where('timeTo','>=',$timeTo)
        ->where(['scheduleStatus'=>Constant::STATUS_0])
        ->get();
```

but I'm not getting the result instead of this I'm getting blank message array where I'm supposed to get the records.

**Question**: 
what I have done wrong? 
suggest me the correct way of query this query.

Schedule Model

```
public function friendsFeed(){
    return $this->hasOne(UserHomeCourt::class,'userHomeCourtId','userHomeCourtId')->with('user')->with('homeCourt');
}
public function userSchedule(){
    return $this->hasOne(UserHomeCourt::class,'userHomeCourtId','userHomeCourtId')->with('homeCourt');
}
```

UserHomeCourt Model

```
public function homeCourt(){
    return $this->belongsTo(HomeCourt::class,'homeCourtId','homeCourtId');
}
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'userId','userId');
}
```

}

HomeCourt Model

```
public function friendsFeed()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserHomeCourt::class, 'homeCourtId', 'homeCourtId');
}
public function userSchedule()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserHomeCourt::class, 'homeCourtId', 'homeCourtId');
}
```

Response I have got from SQL Query[image: Query Result]

Comment: `where('timeFrom','>=',$timeFrom)
        ->where('timeTo','<=',$timeTo)` conditions are diffferent then query.

Comment: then what's the right way to achieve the result of query please make it correct

Comment: also even after doing the same thing I'm getting the blank response

Answer (score 2):

The time check from your sql to eloquent was wrong and when you pass multiple conditions to `where`, you need to set the conditions as an array.

```
$getSchedule= Schedule::with(['userSchedule' => function($query) use ($userId, $homeCourtId) {
    $query->whereHas('homeCourt', function ($query) use ($userId, $homeCourtId) {
        $query->where('userId', $userId)
            ->where('homeCourtId', $homeCourtId);
    })->where('userHomeCourtStatus', 1);
}])
    ->where('timeFrom', '<=', $timeFrom)
    ->where('timeTo', '>=', $timeTo)
    ->where('scheduleStatus', 0)
    ->get();
```

Comment: same thing blank message array :(

Comment: @BhavikBamania i just noticed you have 3 tables in your main query. Can you share your relationships

Comment: yeah in user schedule model I've related these two tables thats why I'm using this here

Comment: yeah give me a sec

Comment: @BhavikBamania share the 3 model data in your post. I'll craft the correct query.

Comment: please check the question I have posted all the models

Comment: @BhavikBamania i've updated the answer based on your model. Check if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145018/discussion-between-bhavik-bamania-and-sandeesh).

Answer (score 0):

try to use `whereHas` function:

```
    Schedule::whereHas('userSchedule', function ($query)
    {
        $query->where('userId', $userId)
            ->where('homeCourtId', $homeCourtId)
            ->where('userHomeCourtStatus', Constant::STATUS_1);
    })
        ->where('timeFrom', '<=', $timeFrom)
        ->where('timeTo', '>=', $timeTo)
        ->where('scheduleStatus', Constant::STATUS_0)
        ->get();
```

Comment: still the same thing.. nothing in message array

Comment: Why you are using the same `foreign_id` and `local_id` in the relation,
it should be different

Comment: can you add your tables structure

Comment: So the primary key in `tblSchedules` is `userHomeCourtId`?

Comment: So you have `scheduleId` in `tblSchedules` and it is related to `scheduleId` in `tblUserHomeCourts`, then the relation should be `hasOne(UserHomeCourt::class,'scheduleId','scheduleId')` instead

Comment: hmmm can you make it simple as much as you can, remove the `with` function after the relations function `hasOne`, and fix all the `foreign_id` and `local_id` in all relations.
and in `UserHomeCourt` model should have `userSchedule` relation, `belongsTo(Schedule::class, 'scheduleId','scheduleId')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145041/discussion-between-aboudeh87-and-bhavik-bamania).